# Paper form to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am doing a Rails 3 app that replaces a paper form for a company. The paper form spans two pages and contains a LOT of fields, checkboxes, drop downs, etc.

I am wondering how to model that in the DB - one approach is to just create a field in the DB for every field on the form (normalized of course). That will make it somewhat difficult to ad or remove fileds since a migration will be needed. An other approach is to do some kind of key/value store (no - MongoDB/CouchDB is not an option - MySQL is required). Doing key/value will be very flexible but will be a pain to query. And it will directly work against ActiveRecord?

Anyone have a great solution for this?

Regards,

Jacob

Comment: How're you planning to store multiple selections - IE: multi-select list, multiple checkboxes for a given question?

Comment: Those attributes would be best stored as key/value, and they won't be THAT bad to query if you have a decent interface. Also, be careful about your normalization when you have check boxes...you're not even in 1NF if you have multivalued attributes.

Comment: Either way has its costs. You have to decide if you want to pay the cost in complex queries (key/value) or data restructuring (field for field, normalized).

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I think as a combo of constants in the model (and text in the DB) and in tables with foreign keys depending on how likely it is that the options need to be administered by the client. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @rownage: Huh? Can you elaborate on the 1NF-part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you model the most common attributes as separate database fields. Once you have setup as many fields as possible then fall back to using a key-value setup for your pseudo-random attributes. I'd recommend a simple approach of storing a `Hash` through the `ActiveRecord` method `serialize`. For example:

```
class TPS < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :custom, Hash
end

@tps = TPS.create(:name => "Kevin", :ssn => "123-456-789", :custom => { :abc => 'ABC', :def => )'DEF' })
@tps.name # Kevin
@tps.ssn  # 123-456-789
@tps.custom[:abc] # ABC
@tps.custom[:def] # DEF
```

Comment: TPS reports...hehe...never get's old

Comment: @Dave :) Apparently it is an actual report (Testing Procedure Specification). I'd never heard of it before Office Space though.

Comment: Wow - that seems like a really nice approach. How would you query the custom attributes?

Answer (score 0):

If your form is fairly static, go ahead and make a model for it, that's a reasonable approach even if it seems rather rudimentary. It's not your fault the form is so complicated, you're just coming up with a solution that takes that into account. Migrations to make adjustments to this are really simple to implement and easy to understand.

Splitting it up into a key/value version would be better but would take a lot more engineering. If you expect that this form will be subject to frequent and radical revisions it may make more sense to build for the future in this regard. You can see an example of the sort of form-builder you might want to construct at something like [WuFoo](http://wufoo.com/) but of course building form builders is not to be taken lightly.

Comment: I know what you mean - I have actually done a simple form builder in ASP many years ago. But there is not enough budget from the client to do that amount of work. But maybe if the form changes a lot - it won't be in the initial version.